# Dynamics crm auto merge duplicate when doing import

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to auto-merge (for contact/account/lead) records that are considered duplicate?

For example: I set the duplicate detection rule based on account name (exact match).

I have an excel file that have 2 rows with column headings (Name|Mobile Phone|Address 1 City)

The data are as follows:

1. Tommy | [blank] | New York
2. Tommy | 31211 | [blank]

I want after the import, the data is automatically merged to: Tommy | 31211 | New York.

Is this possible out-of-the-box? If not, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing "out of the box" to achieve what you're desiring.  [But using this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582489/dynamics-crm-merge-two-contacts-with-c-sharp-code-modified-example-from-sdk), it wouldn't be too terribly difficult to create a custom workflow activity that gets ran on the create of an entity and

- Checks to see if it is a duplicate of an already existing entity (Not sure of how to constrain this only to import if you didn't want to run it all the time)
- If so, performs the merge logic in the link provided